# How do I remove the header from reports in Odoo?

Tags: templates, header, odoo, report, footer

I want to remove the header and footer from my report in Odoo. I tried changing the layout to both basic and external layouts, but I had no success. How can I achieve this, please?

And how can I use paper format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the basic report layout:

**Example:**

```
<template id="MODULE.report_no_hf">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="web.basic_layout">
                <t t-call="MODULE.report_document" />
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

To adjust the report spacing, create a custom paper format:

```
<record id="paperformat_no_hf" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="margin_top">0</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">0</field>
    ...
</record>
```

And link it to the report action:

```
<record id="action_report_no_hf" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="MODULE.paperformat_no_hf"/>
    ...
</record>
```